# A problem related to circle , altitude , triangle.

Tags: geometry, triangles

Consider a $\triangle ABC.$ Draw circle $S$ such that it touches side $AB$ at $A$. This circle
passes through point $C$ and intersects segment $BC$ at $E.$

If Altitude $AD =\frac{21(\sqrt{3}−1)}{\sqrt{2}}\;$
and $\;\angle EAB = 15^\circ,$ find AC.

Here is a sketch that I made:
[image: sketch]

Here , we can calculate AC by Pythagorean theorem  if we find DC . This is where I'm stuck . How can I utilize the information that angle EAB is 15 deg ?

(This is not class-homework , I'm solving sample questions for a competitive exam )

Comment: Isn't the description of $A$ and $C$ asymmetric? You don't think there's a difference between touching and passing through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [user2345215](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/131872/user2345215) pointed out in a comment, a key point to this question is the fact that the circle *touches* $AB$ in $A$. So it isn't a mere intersection but instead a tangentiality. Even with this stronger constraint, the configuration isn't fully determined. If you fix $A$ and $D$, you can still move $B$ on the line $BD$. But $C$ isn't affected by changes to $B$'s position.

[image: Illustration]

So given $A, D, B$ with a right angle at $D$, how can you construct the rest? You can use $\measuredangle EAB=15°$ to construct the line $AE$, and intersecting that with $BD$ you get $E$. Then you can construct the perpendicular bisector of $AE$ since any circle which passes through $A$ and $E$ has to have its center on that bisector. You can also construct a line through $A$ and orthogonal to $AB$. If the circle touches $AB$ in $A$, its center has to lie on that line. Intersecting these two lines gives you $F$, the center of the circle.

Now take a closer look. $GF$ is perpendicular to $AE$, and $AF$ is perpendicular to $AB$. Since $AB$ and $AE$ form an angle of $15°$, so do $AF$ and $GF$. So we have $\measuredangle AFG=15°$ and $\measuredangle AFE=30°$ Due to the [inscribed angle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle_theorem#Theorem) this tells you that $\measuredangle ACD=15°$ no matter where you place $B$. So you know that $AD=AC\cdot\sin15°$ which gives you

$$AC=\frac{AD}{\sin 15°}=42$$

Answer (score 0):

Below is a scanned image of my solution worked out on paper.
[image: page1]

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if instead of using periods, you could meet the character limit by giving a brief description of the image (even just "below is a scanned image of my solution worked out on paper"). This makes certain elements of the site (such as flags and review queues) which only use text work better, and makes the site more accessible to people with impaired vision.

Comment: OK I will do so

Comment: done. Thanks for suggestion.(again character limit)